Moving Emails to Outlook Folders with VBA base in excel mapping
I am trying to move all the unread emails that have in the heather >3 "|" based on an Excel file path stored on my desktop to different folders, and if the folder doesn’t exist, create it and move it. The thing is, it works, but only with the first one. I assume there must be an error that stops it from working, but I am not able to solve it. Can someone shed some light on it?
Option Explicit

Public Sub ProcessUnreadEmails()
    Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim olInbox As Outlook.folder
    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim Header As String
    Dim Words() As String
    Dim ThirdWord As String
    Dim DestFolder As String
    Dim ExcelApp As Object
    Dim Book As Object
    Dim Sheet As Object
    Dim Cell As Object
    Dim folder As Outlook.folder
    Dim Found As Boolean
    Dim Carpeta As Outlook.folder
    Dim Item As Object
    Dim UnreadItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim Filter As String
    
    'Get folder
    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olInbox = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    
    'Non read filter
    Filter = "[UnRead] = True"
    Set UnreadItems = olInbox.Items.Restrict(Filter)
    
    'Open excel
    Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set Book = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\WWOps SR Audit Status-Master.xlsx")
    Set Sheet = Book.Sheets(1)
    
    'Go throught emails
    For Each Item In UnreadItems
        'Check if are emails
        If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then
            Set olMail = Item
            'read subject
            Header = olMail.Subject
            
            'Extract audit_number from header and check if it has necessary format
            Words = Split(Header, "|")
            If UBound(Words) >= 3 Then
                ThirdWord = Trim(Words(2))
                
                'Check if column A contains audit_number stored in ThirdWord
                Found = False
                For Each Cell In Sheet.Range("B2:B8000")
                    If Cell.Value = ThirdWord Then
                        ' Verificar si tiene propietario
                        If Len(Sheet.Cells(Cell.row, 21).Value) = 0 Then
                            DestFolder = "Action Needed"
                        Else
                            DestFolder = Sheet.Cells(Cell.row, 21).Value
                        End If
                        Found = True
                        MsgBox (Found & " Row: " & Cell.row & " GPS Owner: " & DestFolder)
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next Cell
                    
                'move to folder
                If Found Then
                    'check if folder exist or create it
                    On Error Resume Next
                    Set Carpeta = olInbox.Folders(DestFolder)
                    On Error GoTo 0
                    If Carpeta Is Nothing Then
                        Set Carpeta = olInbox.Folders.Add(DestFolder)
                        MsgBox "Carpeta '" & DestFolder & "' creada."
                    End If
                    olMail.Move Carpeta
                    MsgBox ("Moved to folder: " & Carpeta.Name)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next Item
    
    'close Excel
    Book.Close (False)
    ExcelApp.Quit

    'clean
    Set olMail = Nothing
    Set ExcelApp = Nothing
    Set Book = Nothing
    Set Sheet = Nothing
    Set olNs = Nothing
    Set olInbox = Nothing
    Set Carpeta = Nothing
End Sub

Thanks a lot.

Have you tried to step through your code?

Public Sub ProcessUnreadEmails()
    Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim olInbox As Outlook.folder
    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim Header As String
    Dim Words() As String
    Dim ThirdWord As String
    Dim DestFolder As String
    Dim ExcelApp As Object
    Dim Book As Object
    Dim Sheet As Object
    Dim cell As Object
    Dim folder As Outlook.folder
    Dim Found As Boolean
    Dim ExcelOpened As Boolean
    Dim Carpeta As Outlook.folder
    Dim Item As Object
    Dim UnreadItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim Filter As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim a As Long
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim pos As Long
    Dim findOwner As Boolean
    
    count = 0
    moved = False
    ExcelOpened = False
    findOwner = False
    'Get folder
    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olInbox = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    'Non-read filter (updated format without spaces)
    Filter = "[UnRead]=True"
    Set UnreadItems = olInbox.Items.Restrict(Filter)
    
    'Go through emails backward to avoid skipping due to collection modification
    For i = UnreadItems.count To 1 Step -1
        Set Item = UnreadItems.Item(i)
        
        'Check if is an email
        If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then
            Set olMail = Item
            
            ' Read subject
            Header = olMail.Subject
            
            'Check if header contains site_id and if yes extract
            If InStr(Header, "ST-") > 0 Then
                ThirdWord = Mid(Header, InStr(Header, "ST-"), 10)
                
                'Open Excel only if it hasn't been opened yet
                If Not ExcelOpened Then
                    Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
                    Set Book = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\WWOps SR Audit Status-Master.xlsx")
                    Set Sheet = Book.Sheets(1)
                End If
                
                'Check if column B contains audit_number stored in ThirdWord
                Found = False
                For Each cell In Sheet.Range("B2:B8000")
                    If cell.Value = ThirdWord Then
                        'LastColumn = Sheet.Cells(1, Sheet.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).column
                        If Not findOwner Then
                            For a = 1 To 100
                                If Sheet.Cells(1, a).Value = "GPS Owner" Then
                                    pos = a ' Store the column number in pos
                                    findOwner = True
                                    Exit For ' Exit loop once found
                                End If
                            Next a
                        End If
                    
                        ' Check if there's an owner in column U
                        If Len(Sheet.Cells(cell.row, 21).Value) = 0 Then
                            DestFolder = "Action Needed"
                        Else
                            DestFolder = Sheet.Cells(cell.row, pos).Value
                        End If
                        Found = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next cell

                ' Check if folder exists or create it
                count = count + 1
                Set Carpeta = Nothing
                On Error Resume Next
                Set Carpeta = olInbox.Folders(DestFolder)
                On Error GoTo 0
                ' Move to folder
                If Found Then
                    If Carpeta Is Nothing Then
                        Set Carpeta = olInbox.Folders.Add(DestFolder)
                    End If
                    olMail.Move Carpeta
                Else
                    Set Carpeta = olInbox.Folders("Action Needed")
                    olMail.Move Carpeta
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Close Excel if opened
    If Not ExcelApp Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox ("Entra")
        Book.Close (False)
        ExcelApp.Quit
        MsgBox ("Process finish. " & count & " Emails moved.")
    Else
        MsgBox ("No emails moved.")
    End If
    
    ' Clean up
    Set olMail = Nothing
    Set ExcelApp = Nothing
    Set Book = Nothing
    Set Sheet = Nothing
    Set olNs = Nothing
    Set olInbox = Nothing
    Set Carpeta = Nothing
End Sub


Try this edit:
'move to folder
If Found Then
    'check if folder exist or create it
    Set Carpeta = Nothing                   '<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Carpeta = olInbox.Folders(DestFolder)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Carpeta Is Nothing Then
           Set Carpeta = olInbox.Folders.Add(DestFolder)
           MsgBox "Carpeta '" & DestFolder & "' creada."
    End If
    olMail.Move Carpeta
    MsgBox ("Moved to folder: " & Carpeta.Name)
End If

When attempting to reference a non-existent folder, the assignment fails, but when that line fails it does not set Carpetera to Nothing, and Carpeta still references the folder from the previous Item.

Hello, thanks for your help. Now it works better because sometimes it processes 2 emails, whereas before it was only 1. However, I need it to process all of them, around 10 emails each time.

Sub CopyAllPDFsFromFolderToExcel()
    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim pdfFile As String
    Dim pdfFiles As Collection
    Dim i As Integer

    folderPath = "C:\Users\Desktop\Testtt\"
    
    Set pdfFiles = New Collection
    
    pdfFile = Dir(folderPath & "*.pdf")
    

    Do While pdfFile <> ""
        pdfFiles.Add folderPath & pdfFile
        pdfFile = Dir
    Loop

    For i = 1 To pdfFiles.Count

        Shell "C:\Users\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --new-window """ & pdfFiles(i) & """", vbNormalFocus
        
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")
        
        SendKeys "^a", True
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")
        
        SendKeys "^c", True
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")
        
        AppActivate Application.Caption
        
        ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        
        Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
        
       ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Paste
        ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False

        Range("A1").Select
    Next i

    MsgBox "All PDFs copied!"
End Sub


Hello, I think this is wrong, I want to move emails, not copy PDF's

I finally manage to make it works, I attach the final code but I am not able to paste it here. character limit... Thanks for your help.

Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

@ceusito You may put the solution in an answer post and accept it later.
